# How to get limited number of outputs from the query c#

Tags: c#

I need to get only the first value of the query. How can I do that ?

```
Dictionary<int, string> dict = new Dictionary<int, string>();

dict.Add(1, "Jack");
dict.Add(2, "Peter");
dict.Add(3, "Chris");
dict.Add(4, "Peter");

var keys = from entry in dict where entry.Value == "Peter" select entry.Key limit 1;
```

I get an error if I use limit. So what is other ways to limit the output or how to get the first result alone from the query ?

> Error CS0103  The name 'limit' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Use `first` or `take`.

Comment: `dict.Where(x => x.Value == "Peter").Select(x => x.Key).Take(1)`

Comment: When asking a question, if you get an error, it's best to include the error in your question.

Comment: @SlavaUtesinov: That can be collapsed into `dict.First(x => x.Value == "Peter").Key`. The key difference here is that your version renders **a list with one item**, as opposed to the one item itself.

Comment: @Flater Using `First()` you may encounter exception unless you go `?.Key` ...when using `First()`, this does not apply to `FirstOrDefault()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also try this syntax...

```
var key = dict.FirstOrDefault(v => v.Value == "Peter").Key;
```

Edit: Added code for ease of understanding / copy-pasting...
Rextester - http://rextester.com/AIAKRZ95654

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Dictionary<int, string> dict = new Dictionary<int, string>();

            dict.Add(1, "Jack");
            dict.Add(2, "Peter");
            dict.Add(3, "Chris");
            dict.Add(4, "Peter");

            var key = dict.FirstOrDefault(v => v.Value == "Peter").Key;

            Console.WriteLine(key);
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE: Please note when using `FirstOrDefault()` keyword, `?.key` is not required, worst case it will return `0`. The `?.key` is required when using `First()`. Because of this confusion Flater voted this answer down, and deleted his comments from the comment section below. (He probably should have acknowledge and mentioned this factor to give other programmers a heads up / caution sign about this subtle difference between `First()` and `FirstOrDefault()`)

Comment: @Flater  Perhaps it was the rextester which returned default int when I tried this. Did you happen to test this in rextester?

Comment: @Flater it was the difference between ‘First()’ vs ‘FirstOrDefault()’, In your rexster you have used former, and I have used later in the answer above and in rexster. PS: I’m unable to format keywords in comment as I’m using mobile device at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

use First or FirstOrDefault when there can be zero items in the Dictionary:

```
var keys = (from entry in dict where entry.Value == "Peter" select entry.Key).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

Collections have four methods that all of them return one item of the collection:

**First(condition)**
for getting first item that satisfy the condition, if there is no such item, this method will throw exception.

**FirstOrDefault(condition)**
for getting first item that satisfy the condition, if there is no such item, this method will return null.

**Single(condition)**
for getting the only item that satisfy the condition. if the number of items that satisfy the condition is more or less than 1, this method throw exception.

**SingleOrDefault(condition)**
for getting the only item that satisfy the condition. if the number of items that satisfy the condition is more than 1, this method throw exception.